# Prevent TikZ tree text overlapping with later lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to create a family tree with TikZ growing right. I have the tree working, but the text at each node is too long, it overlaps with later lines (e.g. My Family Tree, Paternal GMother and Paternal GFather below). Is there a way to fix this?

[image: broken tikz tree]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\newlength\treeheight
\setlength{\treeheight}{\textheight-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,anchor=west,
  every node/.style={},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8}]
  % parents
  \node {My Family Tree}[edge from parent fork right]
    child { node {Father}
      child{ node {Paternal Gfather}
        child{ node {Paternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Paternal GGmother}}
      }
      child{ node {Paternal Gmother}
        child{ node {Maternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Maternal GGmother}}
      }
    }
    child { node {Mother}
      child{ node {Maternal Gfather}}
      child{ node {Maternal Gmother}}
    }

  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `level distance` in your MWE is the distance between the center of a parent node and the left anchor of the child node. If there are more than one child the edge is splitted at half of the `level distance`. That's why the lines overlap the text if (half of) the node text is longer as (half of) `level distance`.

Using `parent anchor=east` and `growth parent anchor=east` the `level distance` is the distance between the borders of the parent and the childe node.

To avoid an overfull hbox I decrease the `level distance` to 0.5cm in the following example. If it is not necessary to observe the `\textwidth` you can remove this change.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\begin{document}
\newlength\treeheight
\setlength{\treeheight}{\textheight-2cm}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=right,
  anchor=west,
  growth parent anchor=east, % added code
  parent anchor=east, % added code
  level distance=0.5cm, % added code (not necessary)
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8}]
  % parents
  \node {My Family Tree}[edge from parent fork right]
    child { node {Father}
      child{ node {Paternal Gfather}
        child{ node {Paternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Paternal GGmother}}
      }
      child{ node {Paternal Gmother}
        child{ node {Maternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Maternal GGmother}}
      }
    }
    child { node {Mother}
      child{ node {Maternal Gfather}}
      child{ node {Maternal Gmother}}
    }

  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To vertical align the forks add an `align=center` or `align=left` (it aligns the text in the nodes) to the picture options and change the level styles to

```
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2,text width=\widthof{Mother}},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4,text width=\widthof{GGmother}},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8}]
```

In addition horizontal space is saved.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to `TikZ` trees you can use [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) and forget problems computing distances between nodes. The package does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
   for tree={grow=0,parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor)-- +(0:2mm)|-(\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}}
  [My Family Tree
    [father 
        [Paternal Gfather 
                [Paternal GGfather] 
                [Paternal GGmother]] 
        [Paternal Gmother 
                [Maternal GGfather] 
                [Maternal GGmother]]]
    [mother 
        [Maternal Gfather]
        [Maternal Gmother]]] 
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `level distance` to your level settings:

```
level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2,level distance=\treeheight/6},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4,level distance=\treeheight/8},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8,level distance=\treeheight/4}]
```

[image]